# Windows phone application bar

Tags: windows-phone-7, appbar

I have add four icons for my application bar that are yellow . When the theme is set to dark everything is OK but when i set it to light the yellow becomes black any suggestions ?

Comment: Microsoft recommends that: "Custom application bar icons should be 48 x 48 pixels and use a white foreground on a transparent background."

Comment: i have a picture for background

Answer (score 1):

That's default behavior. Icons are inverted if the AppBar background color is too light.